# Selected ListViewItem is not highlighted on TabPage, after selected TabPage changed forth and back

Tags: c#, listview, tabpage

I am currently facing a strange behavior of the C#.Net ListView when used on a TabControl's TabPage.

**Background:** 
I have said TabControl with three TabPages, the ListView is on the first one.

**Scenario:**

- I select one Item in the ListView and its "Selected" property is set to "true"
- I change to another TabPage
- I change back to the first TabPage with the ListView containing the selected Item

**Result:**

The former selected Item in the ListView is not highlighted any longer. Iterating over all Items shows that its "Selected" property is still set to "true".
As soon as I click into the ListView control, I can see the selected Item being highlighted for a short moment, before loosing its highlighting again due to me having clicked somwhere else and therefore deselecting it. 
But neither one of Refresh, Invalidate, RedrawItems, Focus or Select on the ListView leads to the selected Item being highlighted again.

Has anyone of you experienced the same issue and found a proper way to solve this? 
My current solution is to clear the List of SelectedItems on the ListView as soon as the corresponding TabPage is re-focused, hence deselecting every Item and forcing the user to re-select what he wants to be selected.

But since I also noticed that ListBoxes can savely store their selection and display it properly, I would wish for the same feature on the ListView.

Thanks, 
Thomas

Comment: are you re-initialising or doing anything with the listview when you come back to the first tab ?

Comment: @MonishKoyott No, nothing of this kind

Comment: Are you looking for [`ListView.HideSelection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: There is no hint whatsoever that the ListView *should* regain the focus when you select the tabpage again.  Consider setting its HideSelection property to False so the selection is still visible.  And consider the tab control's SelectedIndexChanged event to force the focus back on the control.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, this property never gained my attention so far and is definitively a step in the right direction.

Comment: After setting HideSelection to False, the selected Item is at least shown in gray. But still, calling Focus or Select on the ListView when the corresponding TabPage is re-entered does not put it to the "foreground" in the sence of showing it blue again.